# Transitive dependencies not resolved with <filesystem> resolver

Tags: ant, ivy

I am using ivy 2.4.0 with ant 1.9.2 and I want to be able to push artifacts to a local repository and retrieve them as well as their transitive dependencies. My resolvers look like:

```
<resolvers>
    <filesystem name="local" checkmodified="true" m2compatible="true">
      <ivy pattern="/something/.ivy/[orgPath]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>
      <artifact pattern="/something/.ivy/[orgPath]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" />
    </filesystem>

    <chain name="main" returnFirst="true">
      <resolver ref="local" />
      <ibiblio name="artifactory" 
               checkmodified="true" 
               changingMatcher="regexp" 
               changingPattern=".*-SNAPSHOT.*" 
               m2compatible="true" 
               usepoms="true"
               root="url to artifactory" />
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
```

Artifacts are published (both pom and jar are publications) using:

```
<ivy:deliver deliverpattern="/my project/ivy.xml"/>
<ivy:makepom ivyfile="ivy.xml" pomfile="pom.xml"/>
<ivy:publish resolver="local or artifactory" overwrite="true" publishivy="false">
   <artifacts pattern="/my project/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]" />
</ivy:publish>
```

**I can publish an artifact to my `local` repository however when I fetch it, its transitive dependencies are not retrieved.**

I tried publishing the ivy file as well but that did not change anything and it is driving me crazy because everything works as expected if I publish / fetch from Artifactory repository. What could be missing or being not well configured ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest configuring Artifactory as your default repo, and use a [modules](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/modules.html) directive to tell ivy to use the local repo.

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="artifactory"/>
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="artifactory" m2compatible="true" root="http://path/to/artifactory/repo"/>
        <filesystem name="local">
            <artifact pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
        </filesystem>
    </resolvers>
    <modules>
        <module organisation="myorg1" resolver="local"/>
        <module organisation="myorg2" name="module1" resolver="local"/>
        <module organisation="myorg2" name="module2" resolver="local"/>
    </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

Comment: This is a good idea, thanks. However, my issue is more on the local repo configuration: I can't get transitive dependencies when artifacts are published on my local repo. The layout looks the same as artifactory's though...

Comment: @Jerome Still doesn't work? Odd... Asking an obvious question have you switched off transitive dependencies? Less obvious are you using ivy configurations?